Osmosdr Source Gnu radio
When working with a two-channel LimeSDR, the channels of the Osmocom Source block are not synchronized with each other and start at different times.How can this be fixed?

That's surprising, and I'd encourage you to make 100% sure this is actually true; currently don't have a LimeSDR at hand. Since LimeSDRs don't support "re-syncing" channels, you couldn't correct that. Also, if I remember the LimeSDR on the wire format correctly, I honestly don't know how that could happen, but I'm taking your word for it!
Anyways, you might want to try the "SoapySDR LimeSDR source" that comes with GNU Radio, instead of using the external gr-osmosdr source.
